# What does this formula (to derive the annualized volatility for the VaR) mean?

Tags: finance, notation

I'm faced with the formula shown in the image below, which I just don't understand, in part because I've no grounding in stats, and in part because I don't even understand the notation:

[image]

What's going on here? Is this showing in the first line how to compute the VaR, and then in the second line how to derive the annualized volatility from some of the variables used in the first computation?

I don't even understand the "T time intervals of 1/m years" part. What's an "mth" of a year?  And what does "(sigma) 1/m" mean? Is that the volatility for *one* time period? If so, then don't we need to aggregate the values for all the discrete time periods somehow? I'd expect to see a "sum from 1 to m" somewhere...

I'm totally confused, and any help would be very gratefully received.

Comment: Honestly, when I come across references that use miscegenated phrases like "reverse-engineering a formula" and have godawful typsetting for symbols, the first thing I do is look for a different reference, because you can be pretty sure the writer either doesn't really know what they're talking about or they have little idea of how to communicate it well.

Comment: I agree, but in this case this is "the law", and I have been unable to find an alternative explanation...